# Why I'm getting error message "wrong return type"

Tags: c#, textbox, return

I'm getting the error like

> string Calculate_File_Checksum.Form1.button4_Click(object,
>   System.EventArgs)' has the wrong return type

I don't understand why this is happening ?

I want to return the File checksum to a text box `txtFileChecksum`

Please anybody help me?

here is the code behind that button ...

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        string s = BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(File.ReadAllBytes(txtFileText.Text))).Replace("-", "");
        return s;


        txtFileChecksum.Text = s;
    }
}
```

Edited ...

thanks you all of you, I've done that now ... Its working fine without    **return s;**

Comment: private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e).  Is a void method.  You can not return any value.

Comment: Also, the line after the return statement doesn't make any sense. It will never be executed, since you leave the method with the `return` already.

Comment: So you want to return a variable from an event handler that isn't supposed to do so? What are you trying to do? If you omit `return ...`, isn't `txtFileChecksum.Text = s;` working then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method says its return type is `void` but you return a `string`.

Remove `return s` and it should work. Besides this return type problem, the `return` keyword will get you out of this method. So you will never reach `textFileChecksum.Text = s;`

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to return anything from a method whose return type is void. Let me include one more point that, a function will return (if it has any other return type than `void`) specific value to the calling function. In your case the function is associated with an event so it won't allow any other return type.

Consider that f you change the return type in method signature as string then you will get  error `button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)' has the wrong return type`.

In your code the statement `return s;` is not necessary there, your code will work perfectly without that statement.

Answer (score 0):

Because your core question is already answered I will leave you a suggestion.
I recommend splitting the logical part(calculating the checksum) and the GUI changing part(change of the text) of your code. For example write a method that does calculate the checksum for you like:

```
private string CalculateChecksum(string textFileText) 
{ 
   using (var md5 = MD5.Create()) 
   {
      return BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(File.ReadAllBytes(textFileText))).Replace("-", "");
   }
}
```

and then use this method in your event like:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   txtFileChecksum.Text = CalculateChecksum(txtFileText.Text);
}
```

Note that this also allows you to calculate the checksum somewhere else in your class without having to duplicate the code by just passing in another textFileText.